# Angularjs ng-include и ng-click глюк

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Использую директиву для подмены содержимого блоков, [которая описана тут](http://apparently.me.uk/angularjs-view-specific-sidebars/).

В один *див* ставится атрибут *block-insertion* с названием подгружаемого элемента. В самом подружаемом элементе ставится атрибут  *block-replacement* с таким же названием. И после подменяется содержимое. Сам шаблон блока гружу через *ng-include*.

В подгружаемом шаблоне область видимости родителя есть, и выполняются методы. Но по какой-то причине не работает *ng-click*.

[Вот простой пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/3OPhzVuUqHS7VOGRPZuF)

Не могу понять, в чем причина. Может быть, кто-то поможет разобраться?

Весь код скрипта:

```
var test = angular.module('test', ['sheikcontrolls']);

var sheikContolls = angular.module("sheikcontrolls",[]);

sheikContolls.controller('BaseController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name="Alex";

  $scope.getName = function(){
    return $scope.name;
  };
  $scope.alertName = function(){
    alert($scope.name);
  };
});


//SideBar here
var blocks = {};

test.directive('customOnChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
            element.bind('change', onChangeFunc);
        }
    };
});

test.directive(
    'blockInsertion',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var key = iAttrs.blockInsertion;
                blocks[key] = iElement;

                // Assume that block-insertion directives won't get
                // removed after they're inserted. A more robust
                // implementation would clean these up on $destroy.
            }
        };
    }
);
test.directive(
    'blockReplacement',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var key = iAttrs.blockReplacement;

                // Prepare to move our element to its corresponding
                // block insertion point.
                iElement.remove();

                if (! blocks[key]) {
                    // No matching block insertion, so just hide.
                    return;
                }

                blocks[key].replaceWith(iElement);

                scope.$on(
                    '$destroy',
                    function () {
                        // Restore the insertion element.
                        iElement.replaceWith(blocks[key]);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Обработчики событий в Angular вешаются через `el.on(...)` ([исходный код](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L62)), после того как вы делаете `replaceWith` они отваливаются, т.к. те элементы, на которые вешался обработчик, больше не существуют в DOM. Я бы возможно советовал взглянуть на такую фичу Angular как *transclude*, может быть она поможет в поиске решения.

Comment: В английской версии stackoverflow предложили использовать $compile может кто подскажет каким образом?